# One way to get the speed of set.difference() but use fuzzy matching?

Tags: python, string-matching

I am able to compare two lists with embedded for loops, but the speed of this is quite slow. Is there a way to use set.difference() or some other technique to increase the speed of finding potential fuzzy matches between two lists?

here's my sample

```
matchdict = dicttype

if isinstance(matchdict, collections.defaultdict):
    for i, u in enumerate(list1):
        for i1, u1 in enumerate(list2):
            if func(u, u1) >= cutoff:
                pair = (u, u1)
                #print pair
                #shortstr = min(pair, key=len)
                #longstr = max(pair, key=len)           
                #matchdict[shortstr] = longstr
                matchdict[u].append(u1)

elif isinstance(matchdict, dict):
    for i, u in enumerate(list1):
        for i1, u1 in enumerate(list2):
            if func(u, u1) >= cutoff:
                pair = (u, u1)
                #print pair
                shortstr = min(pair, key=len)
                longstr = max(pair, key=len)           
                #matchdict[shortstr] = longstr
                matchdict[u] = u1     

print 'format is: list1 : list2'
```

Answer (score 0):

to compare two lists you can try this ...

```
sorted(list1) == sorted(list2)
```

in order to get difference between lists try this ...

```
list(set(list1) - set(list2)) + list(set(list2) - set(list1))
```

Comment: can you help me understand how differences between lists will help with fuzzy matching between strings?